# streamSubscription<locationData> and Location still take old values

Tags: flutter, location, mapbox

I have flutter app where I want to mark location from map and follow user until he arrives to location that he marks I used mapBox maps with mapBox-gl package and Location package but when I choose loaction from map and press start to start follow user I follow user location and every thing ok but when I choose another location from map it seems it continue to take old values until I go out the screen and enter again
although when the condition met it stop and every thing ok but I want to stop it when calling function and then start listen again

```
late Location locationChange = Location();
  StreamSubscription<LocationData>? locationsubscription;
calculateDistance()async {

    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("tasks")
        .doc(empname)
        .collection("tasks")
        .doc(taskname)
        .update({
      'start time': DateTime.now().toString().substring(10, 16),
      'estimated time ': double.parse((duration / 60).toStringAsFixed(2))
    });

    locationsubscription =
        locationChange.onLocationChanged.listen((event) async {
         await CacheHelper.sharedPreferences!.reload();
          LatLng tasklatlong =await CacheHelper.getTaskLatLong();
          String? taskname =await CacheHelper.getTaskname();
      print('after initilize');
      var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
      var dLat = deg2rad(event.latitude!-tasklatlong.latitude);  // deg2rad below
      var dLon = deg2rad(event.longitude!-tasklatlong.longitude);
      var a =
          sin(dLat/2) * sin(dLat/2) +
              cos(deg2rad(event.latitude)) * cos(deg2rad(tasklatlong.latitude)) *
                  sin(dLon/2) * sin(dLon/2);
      var c = 2 *atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a));
      var d = R * c*1000; // Distance in km
      print('distance is $d');
      if (d <= 100) {
        print('arrived to location');
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("tasks")
            .doc(empname)
            .collection("tasks")
            .doc(taskname)
            .update(
                {'arrived time': DateTime.now().toString().substring(10, 16)});
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: 'You arrived to location', backgroundColor: approvecolor);
        locationsubscription?.cancel();
        calculateWastedTime();
      }
      else {
        print('not arrived ');
      }
    });
  }
  double deg2rad(deg) {
    return deg * (pi/180);
  }
```

I tried to make another function to stop locationSubscription and then call calculate distance function but still same problem